# Is a US senator supposed to represent their constituency in presidential endorsement?

Tags: united-states, senate, democratic-primary

Is a US senator supposed to represent their constituency?

If I am correct, Bernie won California and all its counties  in 2020 primary.
Senator Harris endorsed Biden, however. Is presidential endorsement a personal preference of a senator? That is my guess so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An endorsement is always a *personal* action, not an official action. Kamala Harris did not endorse Biden in her capacity as the junior Senator from California, she endorsed him as Kamala Harris (who just so happens to be the junior Senator from California). She is not speaking as the representative of her constituents. While politicians might consider the effect of an endorsement on their own political careers, there's not even a moral obligation to endorse based on their constituents' views.

Comment: what kind of things does a senator need to act on behalf of their constituency ?

Comment: @Tim *Need* to? Nothing. The point of a representative democracy is that you elect someone to make decisions, not to mirror polls in their constituency. If X is popular in the constituency but the elected official thinks Y is better for the country, it's perfectly legitimate for them to vote for Y. That said, an elected official *ought* to consider their constituents views when acting as an elected official. Speeches and votes in Congress, for instance, are done on behalf of the constituency.